# Verifying Hydra-generated JWT access_token signature in jwt.io?

Tags: jwt, jwk, fusionauth, hydra

I configured Hydra to return JWT in access_token (`STRATEGIES_ACCESS_TOKEN=jwt`). Pasting the resulting token[1] in jwt.io works—it's decoded successfully and the data looks right. Now I want to verify the signature.

So I open `http://localhost:9000/.well-known/jwks.json` and extract the public RSA keys[2][3], but none of them works—jwt.io gives me "Invalid Signature".

FYI the same error is also thrown by [FusionAuth JWT library](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-jwt). My Scala code to get the keys:

```
    private val hydraVerifiers = {
        val keys = retrieveKeysFromJWKS("http://localhost:9000/.well-known/jwks.json")

        keys.asScala.map(JSONWebKey.parse).map(_.asInstanceOf[RSAPublicKey]).map(RSAVerifier.newVerifier)
    }.toSeq
```

(If you're not familiar with Scala/FusionAuth, the code above retrieves keys from a URL, parses them to `java.security.PublicKey` object, and creates JWT verifiers based on the public keys)

Any suggestions?

[1]

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InB1YmxpYzpjMzQ5NWJkMC0wZDFhLTRiOWMtOWZhNy1hZjE5ZWNlODMxMTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOltdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJpZC5ldmVyeS5leHQuc3RlYW0iLCJleHAiOjE2Mjc3NTI0ODEsImV4dCI6e30sImlhdCI6MTYyNzc0ODg4MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo5MDAwLyIsImp0aSI6IjAxNjRkMzk4LTY4OWQtNDUzZi05YmMxLWVjYTgyMGJkOWY1OSIsIm5iZiI6MTYyNzc0ODg4MCwic2NwIjpbImVpZC5leHRlbmQiLCJvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyJdLCJzdWIiOiIweDMyY2ZkMSJ9.h2XUovsF7e5OI60BnKakbHVQJoNJmxQSsmLMy2MxyxFHQ4VMDdISPbkJVD5fsPCdLVw3RcggSid8S7fHJpDWqgJD0UP1WZBqlYN6E2FYs25QRsn8tvOlb9RqDAq1sqhSA1DhPCSsg0OB37gqQq4M8TjYfH0gqrj6oiU9YvgvlKU2Q7uaXfUjxWNkW_6KCZsdUSAGsHtIT18BWudcry7xafVsbrSdp7HkdRhbbdGCh9-q7lTWx6dJB5gOUTI4TYWCzOZnos48NilIhrk_sZ6V7qk6cxkmGVQflQZ9sLmHGewY6IF7j5OKBDcl-fNGfOyvhn2HkTGzTb_H1uB4dxm1NkopPf4dQHU4A63CnoJLqS_Rhg7aYvdcSyJTtiEGXOQjApP9QkawePsd7JYlSHE7XvYxW7frM0VVO04Fu8HjftMliYKXHct0w9bVeykwRGF_m63VGaain0DjE6H5UKLNdNQvg5r4Azu-hBiR5sH5cL6j26ffEx_P-XnIK5cHyX2A9GHk9V_p6_SiLtKpEuKO4sZPBU4zc6z0J1_aFn-AAtFRpKvHKAfUNCnVacEkXO4k6EfJ3qLkrF2KNIfYCqcTTFl8tPdmbb_n020xdCZNpVKPW_G9qRqpf7okwx9ppGO6OD__uIXNEOcuKD-9pVk2qsdl4RqHAvVO6GNurbcAXQU
```

[2]

```
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
```

[3]

```
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
```

Comment: the key [2] works, jwt.io needs the header and footer `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`
`-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

Comment: @wiradikusuma did you verify that the key is being found (the key id is matching)? Did you try with the `----....` text that @jps suggests?